# Parcelable does not unmarshall nested objects

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable

I am including the whole structure below so you can see what I have done. But it is not working. When I send a `NutHouse` object across activities, the NutHouse arrives but the ArrayList is empty.

```
public class NutHouse implements Parcelable{
    Safety safety = Safety.NICE;
    String name;
    String address;
    ArrayList<Dog> dogs;

    protected NutHouse(Parcel in) {
        safety = in.readParcelable(Safety.class.getClassLoader());
        name = in.readString();
        address = in.readString();
        dogs = in.createTypedArrayList(Dog.CREATOR);
        mice = in.createTypedArrayList(Mouse.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Creator<NutHouse> CREATOR = new Creator<NutHouse>() {
        @Override
        public NutHouse createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new NutHouse(in);
        }

        @Override
        public NutHouse[] newArray(int size) {
            return new NutHouse[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeParcelable(safety, flags);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(address);
        dest.writeTypedList(dogs);
        dest.writeTypedList(mice);
    }
}

class Dog implements Parcelable{
    String name;
    String owner;
    ArrayList<Show> shows;
    HashMap<String,String> friends;

    protected Dog(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        owner = in.readString();
        shows = in.createTypedArrayList(Show.CREATOR);
    }

    public static final Creator<Dog> CREATOR = new Creator<Dog>() {
        @Override
        public Dog createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Dog(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Dog[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Dog[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeString(owner);
        dest.writeTypedList(shows);
    }
}

class Show implements Parcelable{
    String address;
    int placement;

    protected Show(Parcel in) {
        address = in.readString();
        placement = in.readInt();
    }

    public static final Creator<Show> CREATOR = new Creator<Show>() {
        @Override
        public Show createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Show(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Show[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Show[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(address);
        dest.writeInt(placement);
    }
}

enum Safety implements Parcelable{
    NICE,PET,WILD;
    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(final Parcel dest, final int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(ordinal());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Safety> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Safety>() {
        @Override
        public Safety createFromParcel(final Parcel source) {
            return Safety.values()[source.readInt()];
        }

        @Override
        public Safety[] newArray(final int size) {
            return new Safety[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: There's no constructor other than the Parcel constructor -- are the lists ever being assigned values?

Comment: Yes. I use getters and setters. They are not shown (lombok). Do I need empty constructors for everyone?

Comment: Not familiar with Lombok -- normally there'd be no way to create this object outside of using reflection, though.